# Positioning three images together in a row in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to position three pictures together in a row.
I am using beamer. The problem is that the pictures have a tendency to shift into the centre.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{david.jpg}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{stefan.jpg}

\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{Hahn.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps `\hfill` in between the images? And no empty line, since this will act as a linebreak? If this does not help, can you please add a MWE instead of code fragments?

Comment: @samcarter what is MWE? Where shall I ou \hfill?

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Between the graphics, like `\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{david.jpg}\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{stefan.jpg}`

Comment: Offtopic: I don't know what's the content of your images, but be careful, if you specify both the width and the height, the imageratio is most likely disturbed.

Answer (score 3):

If you place an `\hfill` between the images, this will distribute them over the whole linewidth.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{example-image}
            \hfill
            \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
            \hfill
            \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `figure` in beamer, since you presumably don't want your figures to float around.  Here's an alternative.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}\centering
            \begin{tabular}{cp{5mm}cp{5mm}c}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{example-image}
            &&
            \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
            &&
            \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beamer redefines the floating mechanism, so `figures` can safely be used,  however they don't do much more than centring the content and add spacing.